# Where to define database models for Google glass glasswares

Tags: python, google-app-engine, models, google-mirror-api, google-glass

I'm practicing writing glasswares for Google glass based on [python quick start project](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-python). I'd like to collect some extra app specific data from the user and store them in database.

1. How could I achieve that? There is a `model.py` in the main directory of the base code but I'm not sure whether that is the right place or not.
2. Can I use `ndb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code is an AppEngine project, and model.py is indeed the place to put your model code. You'll see there is already a model there that keeps track of your authentication credentials. The ndb should work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

I store user-specific fields on Parse.com.

See the code for my app Glass To Phone: https://github.com/dannyroa/glasstophone-django.

It's built using Python/Django with Parse as database backend.

Here's the part where I store the refresh_token to Parse: https://github.com/dannyroa/glasstophone-django/blob/master/google/views.py#L97.